# Form validation using Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

I am using knockoutJS in my project. Following is the code snippet:

```
<input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" style = "width:100%" placeholder = "Enter name" data-bind="event:{keyup: checkDetails}">

<select class="form-control" id="type" style = "width:100%">
      <option>Type 1</option>
      <option>Type 2</option>
      <option>Type 3</option>
      <option>Type 4</option>
 </select>

<input class="form-control" id="date" type="date" style = "width:100%" data-bind="event:{click: checkDetails}">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id = "add_goal" data-bind = "enable:formFilled">Add Goal</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
       function myViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.formFilled = ko.observable(false);
            self.checkDetails = function(){
                console.log("hello");
                if($("#name").val() != "" && $("#date").val() != ""){
                    self.formFilled = ko.observable(true);
                }
            };
            console.log(self.formFilled());
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
</script>
```

There are three fields and i want to activate the "Add Goal" button only when all fields are filled up. The doubts are: Which event should I add to the HTML5 calender and why is the button not getting activated when I am setting it to true inside "checkDetails" function.

Answer (score 0):

`formFilled` is an observable so you need to set it like a function.

```
if($("#name").val() != "" && $("#date").val() != ""){
    self.formFilled(true);
}
else {
    self.formFilled(false);
}
```

Also your `data-bind="event:{click: checkDetails}">` is looking for click events, i guess this should change to `keyup`.